# CORS headers not being set when using dot (".") in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin

I'm having a strange and weird situtation here.

If I send a request to: `/scenes/?lang=es-ar`, the headers are set just fine and everything seems OK.

[image: Headers are present]

However, if I send one to: `/scenes/?lang=es-ar&sort.asc=creation`, the headers are missing and I'm unable to fetch the response due to cross origin.

[image: Headers are missing]

CORS is automatically managed by Owin's CORS Middleware, so this is out of my hands.

Here is my middleware's configuration:

```
private void ConfigureCors(IAppBuilder application)
{
    CorsPolicy policy = new CorsPolicy()
    {
        AllowAnyHeader = true,
        AllowAnyOrigin = true,
        SupportsCredentials = true,
    };

    policy.Methods.Add("GET");
    policy.Methods.Add("POST");
    policy.Methods.Add("PUT");
    policy.Methods.Add("DELETE");
    policy.Methods.Add("OPTIONS");

    policy.ExposedHeaders.Add("Location");

    application.UseCors(new CorsOptions()
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider()
        {
            PolicyResolver = request => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(policy)
        }
    });
}
```

Why are the headers not being sent on the response?

I'm guessing it has something to with the `"."` (dot) in `sort.asc=creation`

I'm using latest version of **ASP.NET Web Api** (*5.2.3*) and **Microsoft.Owin.Cors** (*3.0.1*)

Answer (score 2):

There might be a possibility that hosting server IIS might be intercepting the pre-flight requests. To ensure ASP.NET handles OPTION requests, add the following in web.config:

```
        <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" 
              type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
              preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
          </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
```

In my opinion this is not a decent choice to use `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` with WebAPI, if you're planning to use IIS as hosting environment. A better choice for Asp.net WebAPi would be [Asp.net web API implementation of CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).